# Neo4j shell import with dates relationships is so slow

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a problem to add DATE relationships to events. When I try to import with neo-shell, it lasts forever with only 10 lines of data.

First I used Mark Needham's [time tree](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2014/04/19/neo4j-cypher-creating-a-time-tree-down-to-the-day/) because I'll use date ranges, tweaked [neo4j conf files](http://jexp.de/blog/2014/06/load-csv-into-neo4j-quickly-and-successfully/) as suggested by Michael on his blog to optimise import operations. 
I'm using the latest 2.2 RC1 version and my Pc is a corei7 with 8GB of RAM.

The model is quite simple:

```
(Person)-[:HAS_A]->(BirthCertificate)-[:WRITTEN]->(City)
(BirthCertificate)-[:SIGNED]->(Year)-[:HAS_MONTH]->(m)-[:HAS_DAY]->(d)
```

The csv file looks like that (only 10 lines so it should be fast)

```
event,city,date_birth,uuid
Birth,Paris,1550-11-21,58697124-af4b-42ea-9002-60316fe619b1
```

and the script to import it with neo4j-shell:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///home/test/birth.csv" as csvLine
WITH csvLine, toInt(substring(csvLine.date_birth,0,4)) as year, toInt(substring(csvLine.date_birth,5,2)) as month, toInt(substring(csvLine.date_birth,8,2)) as day
MATCH (y:Year  {year: year})
MATCH (m:Month {month: month})
MATCH (d:Day   {day: day})
MERGE (n:Event { source: csvLine.event, date: csvLine.date_birth })
MERGE (n)-[:SIGNED]->(y)-[:HAS_MONTH]->(m)-[:HAS_DAY]->(d)
WITH n, y, m, d
RETURN n;
```

I suppose I'm doing it wrong but I didn't manage to fix the query. Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: How big of a time tree did you create? Did you index the label/properties in the time tree?

Comment: I don't have a solution, but I see some odd things; your last `with` clause looks entirely unneeded to me.  Also, why so many `MATCH` clauses first?  What data already exists in your DB that you're doing `MATCH` there and not `MERGE`?  Any indexes at all?

Comment: The time tree starts in 1500 till 2000. I only indexed the Year: CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (y:Year) ASSERT y.year IS UNIQUE

Comment: The rest of the DB is composed of a City node, a Person and Event with indexes on uuid for person and city name

Comment: @user4569126 how did you end up resolving this?

Comment: use the admin tool everything else can be flowed(because of the way it's used/configured or tool lmitations)